# how to call two fields of the same table using GetRolesForUser using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to send a call to another field of my same table but I don't know how to do it since I am only calling a field

```
  public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        masterEntities db = new masterEntities();
        
  string data = db.registro.Where(x => x.usuario == username).FirstOrDefault().idrol;


        string[] result = { data };
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
 public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        masterEntities db = new masterEntities();
        
     string data =
      db.registro.Where(x => x.usuario == username).FirstOrDefault().idrol;
     string data1 =
    db.registro.Where(x => x.usuario == username).FirstOrDefault().lineainvestigacion;


        string[] result = { data,data1 };
        return result;
    }
```

and in my view in .cshtml I show it like this:

```
 @if (User.IsInRole("coordi")&& User.IsInRole("Ingeniería de Software"))
            {


  ..put code with what it will take permissions

}
```